# Linking errors 2005, and 1169 when trying to overload the << operator

Tags: c++, overloading

I get a linking error when i try to compile this code. I need to overload the output operator to display a three dimensional vector class I am not sure where to go from here any help is appreciated.

**Vect3D.h**

```
#ifndef VECT3D_H
#define VECT3D_H

#include <iostream>

class Vect3D
{
public:
Vect3D();
Vect3D(double xVal, double yVal, double zVal);

double getX() const { return x; }
double getY() const { return y; }
double getZ() const { return z; }
double magnitude() const { return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z); }

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out);

void setX(double xVal) { x = xVal; }
void setY(double yVal) { y = yVal; }
void setZ(double zVal) { z = zVal; }

private:
double x;
double y;
double z;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out)
{

os << "(" << out.x << ", " << out.y << ", " << out.z << ")";
return os;
}

#endif
```

**Vect3D.cpp**

```
using namespace std;

#include "Vect3D.h"

Vect3D::Vect3D()
    : x(0), y(0), z(0)
{ }  // empty body

Vect3D::Vect3D(double xVal, double yVal, double zVal)
    : x(xVal), y(yVal), z(zVal)
{ }  // empty body
```

**TestCode.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "Vect3D.h"
int main()
{
Vect3D v;
const Vect3D zero;
Vect3D v1(1, 2, 3), v2(7.5, 8.5, 9.5);
const Vect3D con(4, 5, 6);

cout << "Testing overload of << operator" << endl;
cout << v1;
cout << endl;
cout << "Should be:" << endl;
cout << "(" << v1.getX() << ", " << v1.getY() << ", " << v1.getZ() << ")" <<             endl << endl;

cout << "Testing chaining of overload of << operator" << endl;
cout << v1 << endl;
cout << "Should be:" << endl;
cout << "(" << v1.getX() << ", " << v1.getY() << ", " << v1.getZ() << ")" << endl << endl;

cout << "Testing overload of << operator for const Vect3D's" << endl;
cout << con << endl;
cout << "Should be:" << endl;
cout << "(" << con.getX() << ", " << con.getY() << ", " << con.getZ() << ")" << endl << endl;

cout << "Testing ostream parameter passing for the << operator" << endl;
stringstream sout;
sout << con;
string s = sout.str();
cout << s << endl;
cout << "Should be: " << endl;
cout << "(4, 5, 6)" << endl << endl;
cout << endl << endl;
return 0;
}
```

**Errors:**

> Error  1   error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class Vect3D const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVVect3D@@@Z) already defined in TestCode.obj   G:\overloadAssignment\overloadAssignment\Vect3D.obj

---

> Error  2   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   G:\overloadAssignment\Debug\overloadAssignment.exe  1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I have added the errors in.

Comment: The definition of the output operator is in the header. Add `inline` or move it to the implementation file (where the ctors are).

Comment: I don't understand.  Just an FYI I can't edit TestCode.cpp

Comment: You don't need to change `TestCode.cpp`. Just move `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out) {...}` from `Vect3D.h` to `Vect3D.cpp`.

Comment: SO doesn't work that way. If you have another question, ask another (new) question. Include your code (only the relevant part) for the new question there.

Answer (score 0):

This directive has been used assiduously in other sections of this tutorial. When the preprocessor finds an #include directive it replaces it by the entire content of the specified header or file. See more information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).

So you have `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out)` definition in `Vect3D.h` and you include this file in both `TestCode.cpp` and `Vect3D.cpp`. Thus you compile this function twice in `Vect3D.obj` and `TestCode.obj`. And when you try to link program, linker says that you have multiple definitions, and linker does not know what definition is right.

You need to put your implementation in `Vect3D.cpp` to compile it just once.

**`Vect3D.h`**

```
#ifndef VECT3D_H
#define VECT3D_H

#include <iostream>

class Vect3D
{
public:
Vect3D();
Vect3D(double xVal, double yVal, double zVal);

double getX() const { return x; }
double getY() const { return y; }
double getZ() const { return z; }
double magnitude() const { return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z); }

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out);

void setX(double xVal) { x = xVal; }
void setY(double yVal) { y = yVal; }
void setZ(double zVal) { z = zVal; }

private:
double x;
double y;
double z;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out);

#endif
```

**`Vect3D.cpp`**

```
using namespace std;

#include "Vect3D.h"

Vect3D::Vect3D()
    : x(0), y(0), z(0)
{ }  // empty body

Vect3D::Vect3D(double xVal, double yVal, double zVal)
    : x(xVal), y(yVal), z(zVal)
{ }  // empty body

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vect3D& out)
{

os << "(" << out.x << ", " << out.y << ", " << out.z << ")";
return os;
}
```